# Creating gui objects in Red language

Tags: user-interface, object, rebol, red

Is it possible to use `make` command to create gui `object` in Red/Rebol. I tried following:

```
view [
    do [guiobj: make object! [
             t: text "text"
             f: field "fld"
             b: button "button" ] ; end make object

        obj1: make guiobj
        obj2: make guiobj ]  ; end do

    below
    obj1  
    obj2 ]  ; end view
```

But I get following error:

```
*** Script Error: field has no value
*** Where: f
*** Stack: view layout do-safe 
*** Script Error: VID - invalid syntax at: [obj1 obj2]
*** Where: do
*** Stack: view layout cause-error
```

I know `compose` can be used but can above code be made to work using `make` and `object` commands?

Comment: Of course. I did talk about this and linked to examples in some of my answers

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256166/5798459

Comment: Just wanted to add, this is a good question, but I get the feeling you're trying to run before you can crawl. Please do check out the community here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol and on gitter

Comment: [VID](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/vid.html#_overview) (the spec handed to `view` or `layout`) is a dialect—it is processed and converted into [a face tree](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_the_face_tree) (in the case of `layout` is not yet a descendant of a screen face). It is not Red *do* code though does have some evaluative properties—using outside of `view` and `layout` will almost always produce an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_face_object): *Face objects are clones of face! template object.*

It's possible to build up UIs without using [VID](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/vid.html#_overview)—understanding that will help you understand how to manipulate the output from `layout` (and `view`). What you lose building things from scratch is the layout feature that VID offers, but we can get the best from both worlds. Let's have a go:

### Window Without VID

First we'll need a place to put all our elements:

```
our-window: make face! [
    type: 'window
    text: "Our Window"
    size: 500x500
]
```

Now let's stick some things in there:

```
our-window/pane: reduce [
    make face! [
        type: 'text
        offset: 20x20
        size: 160x28
        text: "Text"
    ]
    make face! [
        type: 'field
        offset: 200x20
        size: 160x24
        text: "Field"
    ]
    make face! [
        type: 'button
        offset: 380x20
        size: 160x28
        text: "Button"
    ]
]
```

And now we can take a look at it:

```
view our-window
```

Note that the objects in `our-window/pane` are kind-of like the objects that would be generated in this example:

```
our-vid-window: layout [
    text 160 "Text"
    field 160 "Field"
    button 160 "Button"
]
```

As I said, with this approach you have to manage sizes and offsets yourself. What we can do is generate our row, take those face objects and append it to our window.

### Stealing Generated Faces from VID

Indeed we can actually create these objects with `layout` and drop them in `our-window`:

```
make-row: func [/local row face kid][
    row: layout copy/deep [ ; copy so the strings are unique
        text 160 "Text"
        field 160 "Field"
        button 160 "Button"
    ]

    ...
]
```

*Using techniques from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391167/292969) you can even apply global words to each of these faces and will still work.*

Before we do though, we're going to check if `our-window` has any children and adjust the offset of each of the new faces to appear below the last child:

```
if kid: last our-window/pane [
    ...

    foreach face row/pane [
        face/offset/y: face/offset/y + kid/offset/y + kid/size/y
    ]
]
```

To get the window sizing right, we're also going to adjust the generated row size and apply thus:

```
row/size/y: row/size/y + kid/offset/y + kid/size/y

...

our-window/size: row/size
```

And then the fun part:

```
append our-window/pane row/pane
```

Bringing this all together, we can generate a nicely sized window.

```
our-window: layout [
    button "Add a Row" [make-row]
]

make-row: func [/local row face kid][
    row: layout copy/deep [
        text 160 "Text"
        field 160 "Field"
        button 160 "Button"
    ]

    if kid: last our-window/pane [
        row/size/y: row/size/y + kid/offset/y + kid/size/y

        foreach face row/pane [
            face/offset/y: face/offset/y + kid/offset/y + kid/size/y
        ]
    ]

    our-window/size: row/size

    append our-window/pane row/pane
]

make-row
make-row
make-row

view our-window
```

Comment: For old-timers, adding `'across` in the `row` spec and `show our-window` after the `append`, this last example works in Rebol/View 2.7.8 as well : )

Comment: What is 'panel' ( http://www.red-by-example.org/index.html#0panel ) for? Can we not use it here?

Comment: `panel` is akin to a `<div>` in HTML—it creates a face object that itself has child objects. It could indeed be used here, would make the positioning loop redundant (`foreach face row/pane [...]`).

Comment: Addition of code with `panel` will make your answer even more comprehensive.

Comment: @rnso Am somewhat reluctant to—it does change the code and resultant structure sufficiently that it require an extended explanation in itself.